# Exclude template tags in django compress

Tags: django, django-compressor

Is there a way to skip tags that are not within the `compress` tag? For example, it seems like it is trying to load other `templatetags`:

```
Invalid template /Users/david/Desktop/Avails/templates/associate_titles.html: 'extras' is not a valid tag library: ImportError raised loading apps.main.templatetags.extras: cannot import name convert_time_to_minutes
Found 'compress' tags in:
    /Users/david/Desktop/Avails/templates/price_tier_update.html
    /Users/david/Desktop/Avails/templates/cc_check.html
    ...
```

Comment: Is this using `django-compressor`?

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr yes